# .sh file in use by sftp after uploading and can't be executed

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu

I'm using mobaxterm for ssh/ftp access. I first create a file `test.sh`. Then I edit the file and save it (it automatically uploads). Now I do

```
chmod 755 test.sh
```

and then try to run it with `./test.sh`, but I get

```
-bash: ./test.sh: Text file busy
```

I ran `lsof` and found this line:

```
sftp-serv 1526                  root    3w      REG              253,1        0     919981 /root/test.sh
```

Which I believe means the file is still in use by the ftp program. Is this normal behavior? How do I get around this and run my script?

Comment: Can you perform other operations with the test.sh file like read, edit or delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is in use by the ftp, I think your automation does not terminate the ftp after the upload hence the connection stays open (this is why it looks like file is being used by other process. You can either run `kill` on the ftp process that is occupying your file or fix your automation so it kills the connection after the upload.